# Transition duration css two way

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I need two way transition duration for slow displaying description, but not work in this code:

```
.sln-steps-description{
    display:none;
    transition: all 2s;
}

#salon-step-services .sln-service:nth-child(1):hover .sln-steps-description{
    display:block;
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: block to none cannot be divided into steps (none or block , there is nothing in between), try with opacity 0 to 1 can be divided in thousands of steps if transition is very long.

Comment: Do you want fade in effect?

Comment: Yes, opacitiy work with transition, but there is blank space: https://prntscr.com/p3y708. This is reason why I use display property instead, but there not work transition:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yFvarA8v6KsedwKW0IqPQG0xSFxgkB8e/view?usp=sharing